# How do I fold nodes of an XML element using lens?

Tags: xml, haskell, haskell-lens

I'm using [xml-lens](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xml-lens) package to process XML.

Given an [`Element`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xml-lens-0.1.6.3/docs/Text-XML-Lens.html#t:Element), I want to perform `concatMap`-like computation on its `elementNode :: [Node]` field. Specifically, a `NodeElement` satisfying some condition should produce some more `NodeElement`s, and all other cases (the rest of `NodeElement`s and other `Node` constructors) should produce a singleton list. It then should get concatenated into `[Node]` and used as a value to overwrite current `elementNode` of a given `Element`.

I'm struggling to write proper lens incantation to do that. Here's what I managed to come up with so far:

```
over nodes $ concatMapOf someLensMagic (myFun :: Element -> [Node])
```

It typechecks, but I'm failing to implement `someLensMagic`. Help with that would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straighforward solution is, [much like bergey suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56780542/2751851), writing a wrapper around `myFun` so that it can handle `Node`s rather than `Element`s:

```hs
myFun' :: Node -> [Node]
myFun' n = case n of
    NodeElement el -> myFun el
    _ -> [n]
```

`myFun'` can then be used with plain `concatMap` (as opposed to `concatMapOf`) to modify the `nodes` field:

```hs
over nodes (concatMap myFun')
```

As it happens, there is a piece of *lens* magic that can be used as an alternative way of writing the wrapper. The [`outside`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.17/docs/Control-Lens-Prism.html#v:outside) combinator turns a prism into a lens that targets a function, allowing us to, in effect, edit what a function does in a specific case. In practice, it looks like this:

```hs
over nodes (concatMap $ set (outside _Element) myFun (:[]))
```

The argument to `concatMap` is a function that behaves like `(:[])` except if the argument matches `_Element`, in which case it becomes `myFun` on the underlying element. That is, in essence, abstracted pattern matching. To drive the point home, we can try imitating the style of definition of `myFun'` above using `outside`:

```hs
myFun' :: Node -> [Node]
myFun'
    = outside _Element .~ myFun
    $ \n -> [n]
```

Answer (score 1):

If `myFun` explains what you want to do with a `NodeElement` constructor, and you want an empty list for other `Node` constructors, you can use `concatMapOf _Element`.

To provide a singleton list for other constructors, you should modify `myFun` to handle all constructors of `Node`.  Then you can use `concatMap myFun`, rather than `concatMapOf`.  (You could use `concatMapOf traverse myFun` in this case, but it's harder to understand.)

There is no way to write `someLensMagic` that will generate the singleton list, because there is no way to extract an `Element` from a `NodeComment` (for example).

Comment: I don't really want to extract an `Element` from a `NodeComment`. I just want to leave it as is.

Answer (score 0):

One way of treating certain child nodes differently in a `Fold` it to use [`to`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.17.1/docs/Control-Lens-Getter.html#v:to) to put them in different branches of an `Either` according to the condition, and then use [`beside`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.17.1/docs/Control-Lens-Traversal.html#v:beside), a function that lets you apply a different `Traversal` to each branch of the `Either`.

For example, this function should return the child `Node`s of an `Element`, with the particularity that for nodes which satisfy the condition, their child nodes are returned instead:

```
foldDifferently :: (Node -> Bool) -> Fold Element Node
foldDifferently p =
      nodes 
    . folded 
    . to (\n -> if p n then Right n else Left n) 
    . beside id (_Element . nodes . folded)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've ended up with two consecutive `concatMap`s:

```
over nodes (concatMap $ concatMapOf _Element myFun) element
```

It is suboptimal solution, so I ain't marking it as answer and welcome any other suggestions.